# Navigation Drawer. Как сделать чтобы навигация не исчезала в планшетнике?

Tags: android, java

Navigation Drawer.как сделать что бы навигация не исчезало в планшетнике... вот как на рисунке  [image: Imgur]

Сделаю по примеру: [Android Custom Navigation Drawer](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/). На телефоне все хорошо, а на планшетнике навигация исчзает

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: имеется ввиду как у вконтактика. Но там не NavigationDrawer, а SlidingMenu.  
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [SetDrawerLock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) позволяет заблокировать меню в нужном положении.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: и он будет поверх всего контента

Comment: Хмм ну и соответствующий лэйаут для планшетов сделать, чтобы drawer был виден.

Comment: @Deadkenny это костыли

Comment: @Deadkenny костыли делать разные лэйауты для разных устройств? Нет, не костыли. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: @Deadkenny речь идет не о разных разметках для телефонов и мланшетов, а об использовании таким образом этого элемента навигации.

Comment: @Andreich вопрос был про NavigationDrawer. А использовать его или нет уже пускай автор решает. Всё зависит от того, какая у него навигация. Есть в support library еще SlidingPaneLayout http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl3-lzlzOJI в чем разница объясняют вот тут.